# Data structure to represent network flow

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph, network-flow

What would be the correct data structure to represent this network flow? Can anyone also explain the chosen data structure?

[Click here to see the network flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR2l8.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to inline the image and also clarify what exactly you're searching for: a data class?, a `record`? Also, what exactly should be represented: packets?, connections?, routes? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you comment @AlexanderLeithner! Unfortunately I'm unable to inline the image due to the lack of reputation points. The eventual goal of the task is to implement an algorithm for finding a maximum generated flow. All that is given is to choose data structure to represent a flow network which is in the image. Should be straightforward but I am not quite sure how to approach it

Answer (score 0):

You likely want a labeled, directed graph. It might look something like this

```
object node
    neighbors : list<pair<node, int>>
    label : int
```

The neighbors would be represented by a node, as well as the number that is placed on the edge in between them. Every node would also have a label itself. The entire structure would then be the collection of all nodes.